# Can chrome browser be updated on Microsoft Hosted agent vs2017-win2016

Tags: azure-devops

Microsoft Hosted agent vs2017-win2016 comes with a chrome browser version 77 as of now, but I would like it to be 79. How can this be updated if at all it can be? appreciate your help. There seems to be an open issue here  [chrome update on azure MS hosted agents](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/issues/861) , but not sure if there is a way to get chrome 79

[This has the version details of chrome that are included in this agent image](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/win/Windows2016-Readme.md)

Comment: Just wanted to check in after the weekend what the status on this issue was?

Comment: I am looking at this link to know if the chrome is updated in the image or not
https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/win/Windows2016-Readme.md  , I hope this is the correct URL to monitor and I don't see that its README has been updated. Its reporting Chrome 77

Comment: This is the fault of our delay. Recently we have other busy releases. Will notify the team who managing the readme in github. Does the script work for you also? If yes, appreciate for accept it then others could know it is work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the Hosted agent will be updated approximately weekly. We are trying to implement our agent scripts so that our agent would catch the latest update timely.

As I checked in Hosted VS2017-win2016, the chorme latest version has been `78`:

[image]

*Will let the team which own the images source code know this and update the `readme` content in github.*

---

But it still could not match what you want `79`. So, you can try with below powershell script to upgrade the `Chorme` version on your side:

```
$theurl = "http://dl.google.com/edgedl/chrome/install/GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise64.msi"

mkdir c:\tmp

$output = "c:\tmp\chrome.msi"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $theurl -OutFile $output -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

msiexec /q /i c:\tmp\chrome.msi

start-sleep -Seconds 300 # sleep for 5 mins just to allow updates to be processed 

Remove-Item -Path c:\tmp\chrome.msi –Force
```

[image]

You could check [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/b0mv9d/updating_google_chrome_through_powershellpowercli/) for further conversation on how to upgrade chrome version manually.

Comment: This works, but my agents use different drive letters, one is C:\ and others are D:\ (maybe? Or temp is always on D: ?)  So that won't work the 2nd time when it switched to another agent.  What is the system directory name?  $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory).  So I could use something like $(windows.root drive letter)/Program Files... 

I got error message like this the 3rd time it ran my powershell script:
Get-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe' because it does not exist.